# A source file named `DebuggerScript` eats my CPU in Chrome Devtools

Tags: google-chrome, javascript-debugger

I noticed that when I debug my code with Chrome Devtools, it's obviously slower than it was. Then I recorded its profile and found there is a script named `DebuggerScript._frameMirrorToJSCallFrame` eating most of my CPU, see the picture:

[image: High CPU]

But why? And how can solve this?

Comment: I have noticed this phenomenon too. It is much less noticable in the "Canary" build of chrome. Some of the discussion surrounding the issue can be found in this issue tracking ticket:
[294214](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=294214) There are more tickets about the problem but this one had the best comments. Some of the comments in the issue allude to using [Remote Debugging Protocol](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/debugger-protocol) to get profiling data without the noise added by DevTools itself.

Comment: For me it's totalling 10 seconds when loading an embedded YouTube video, stalling the page and crashing it altogether if the embed is added dinamically. `DebuggerScript._frameMirrorToJSCallFrame` calls in `DebuggerScript.currentCallFrame` take 20–70ms each, with a load of GC events in them. It's not related to extensions and cookies but the issue is absent from Incognito. :(

Answer (score 3):

I found what seems to be the issue: [Async call stack](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/async-call-stack/). Which makes sense since every `DebuggerScript._frameMirrorToJSCallFrame` call is started by `addEventListener`, exactly where an async call stack can be originated.

[image: Developer Tools > Sources > Async]

Uncheck it and you'll be fine.